# PF autocomplete showing wrong label when validation fails

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having a weird behaviour with primefaces' `autocomplete`.

The component works perfectly fine when I submit a form without validation errors, or with errors on other form fields. However, if validation fails on the autocomplete, the label is replaced by the item `@Id` field.

I suspect something is wrong with the converter I'm using. What the converter does, basically, is get the entity's @Id value and insert the actual entity in the component's attribute map with the @Id value as its key.

Here is my xhtml:

```
                            <p:autoComplete
                                id="autoComp"
                                value="#{action.timeTable}"
                                completeMethod="#{action.timeTables}"
                                var="tt"
                                itemLabel="#{tt.description}"
                                itemValue="#{tt}"
                                dropdown="true"
                                minQueryLength="3"
                                forceSelection="true"
                                converter="entityConverter"
                                size="30"
                                required="true"
                                maxResults="10">

                                <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" />

                            </p:autoComplete>
```

And here is my converter code:

```
@FacesConverter("entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        return component.getAttributes().get(value);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object obj) {

    if (obj instanceof String) {
        return obj.toString();
    }

    if (obj != null) {
        String id;

        try {
            id = this.getId(getClazz(ctx, component), obj);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new ConverterException("msg");
        }

        id = id.trim();

        component.getAttributes().put(id, getClazz(ctx, component).cast(obj));

        return id;

    }
    return null;
}

private Class<?> getClazz(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component) {
    //get entity's class
}

private String getId(Class<?> clazz, Object obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    // get entity's ID value
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your converter is right, as a failed validation does not trigger a conversion of values and PrimeFaces p:autoComplete uses the submitted value to display when the validation fails instead of the previously set correct one. We fixed this by changing the `AutoCompleteRenderer` by replacing

```
if(ac.isValid()) {
    requestMap.put(var, ac.getValue());
    itemLabel = ac.getItemLabel();
}
else {
    Object submittedValue = ac.getSubmittedValue();
    itemLabel = (submittedValue == null) ? null : String.valueOf(submittedValue);

    if(itemLabel == null && ac.getValue() != null) {
        requestMap.put(var, ac.getValue());
        itemLabel = ac.getItemLabel();
    }
}
```

with

```
if(ac.isValid()) {
    requestMap.put(var, ac.getValue());
    itemLabel = ac.getItemLabel();
}
else {
    // Display label of previously set value if validation fails
    itemLabel = ac.getItemLabel();

    if(itemLabel == null && ac.getValue() != null) {
        requestMap.put(var, ac.getValue());
        itemLabel = ac.getItemLabel();
    }
}
```